# enterprise originate ignores SIP 302

Tags: sip, voip, fusionpbx

call comes in pstn gateway
Rings ring group
Extensions in the ring group have call forwarded to pstn numbers
The call should ring the pstn numbers

e.i: ring group test_rg has two extensions 1000 and 1001 and 1000 are registered from IP phone and in IP Phone I set call forwarding to my mobile number. When I call ring group it called 1000 and 1001. 1000 return 302 Temporary moved with new contact header with my mobile number. But FreeSWITCH is not processing 302 message and IP phone continues to send 302 until timeout.

I am facing this issue only when ring group strategy is the enterprise in all other it working fine.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There maybe a fix for this in the next major release 4.4 and already  in the master branch. Reason this would may work is the Call Forward was completely rebuilt to prevent a user causing and infinite loop with their call forward.

When 4.4 is released follow the version upgrade instructions carefully. Make sure your delete your 'user exists' dialplan then go to Advanced -> Upgrade -> App Defaults for it to generate a new on for you.

- Update 4.4 has been released as of 5 April 2018.